# Knockout Template Binding If: option changes from true to true, rerenders template

Tags: knockout.js

I have found that if I have a template binding such as the following:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'mytemplate', if: myObservable() == 1 || myObservable() == 2  } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

knockout will re-render mytemplate when myObservable changes directly from 1 to 2. The if statement never goes into a false state, yet knockout re-renders the entire template.

Is this a knockout bug?

The problem can easily be avoided by switching to the following structure:

```
<!-- ko if: myObservable() == 1 || myObservable() == 2 -->
<!-- ko template: { name: 'mytemplate' } --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

This seems quite non-obvious to me that the native if binding would be different from the if option in the template binding. Quoted from the knockout documentation on the template binding:

> Native templating is the mechanism that underpins foreach, if, with,
>   and other control flow bindings.

Why do these two uses of if: bindings differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Knockout 2.2 changing the value in the if binding would cause a re-render even when changing from truthy to truthy value (i.e. 1->2 in your case). 
That was fixed in 2.2. I guess, this issue is still present in 'if' condition in template binding.

You can read a bit more about if and re-render in [this excellent post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html)